# Is it possible to implement OpenID using only javascript

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, steam-web-api

### Question

Is it possible to use OpenID login using only client side technologies?

Basicly I want to implement OpenID for steam login, I have found very few examples online, mostly in PHP using pre existing libraries.

My goal is to create a client side only solution using only Javascript and HTML. The understanding I have of OpenID is very limited so any resources to better help me understand would also be very welcome.

Any help is appreciated.

I have looked over http://openid.net/developers/libraries/ and found http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/ but I am unsure if it will work outside of a server envrionment.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I have the exact same question. Just wondering if you ever figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, yes. But then your server will not have any way to verify the data the client sends you.

If you really trust the client, this might be fine. But the normal OpenID process only trusts your own server and the remote OpenID server, but not the client - which is why your server calls back to the OpenID server after the client told your server the login.